# .NET Core console app and aspnetcore_environment variable

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application

I have a .net core CONSOLE app.  In the code I am reading in the appropriate environment specific appsettings.dev.json, appsettings.uat.json etc.

```
  var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
  configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
```

When this is run directly in Visual Studio the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable is set from the launchSettings.json file or from amending the project properties, debug tab and the correct appsettings.environment.json file is read.

When i want to publish the project via Visual Studio i.e. right click project and publish (i.e. I do not want to do this via the command line) I select the appropriate .pubxml file held within PublishProfile folder.  In this .pubxml file I have set the environmentName.

```
  <EnvironmentName>dev</EnvironmentName>
```

However, when running the exe that is produced by the publish process - the environmentName variable specified above is always blank and consequently it doesn't pick up the correct environmentName setting and hence the appropriate appsettings.environment.json file is not read in.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to run published .exe file try this way in command line(powershell):

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="dev";yourfile.exe
```

Comment: I don't want to pass in the variable value when the exe is run, i would like it published with this appropriate value set, which is what i thought the purpose of setting it in the pubxml file was.

Comment: It's about the environment variable of OS that you want to run your app, so you should set environment variable for your machine, please see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Yes, i realise that but i want it set as part of the publish process in Visual Studio (not via command line publish).  Already read that article.

Comment: It's not related to how you publish your app and your app read variable from your environment host machine.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that if I change the actual Machine environment variable (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT), the deployed application adjust accordingly.

Remember! (This application is already published - Its behavior changes as I update the variable on the box and restart the application)

Click to see image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPPwt.jpg)

**ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** : When it's set to Production my application uses the appsettings.production.json file

**ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** : When it's set to Development my application uses the appsettings.Development.json file

Click to see image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BaHN.jpg)

I also discovered that I actually had to restart my Visual Studio 2019 in order for the newly added environment variable to take affect. Basically, I believe the environment variables are being cached some how behind the scenes. Therefore, if you do add another variable you may have to restart Visual Studio in order for them to take affect. ... Hummmm